# Waiting for copy process to finish

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to wait for the copy process to finish before running another command?
I tried `Start-job` and `Wait-Job`, but it doesn't work.

```
    $func = {
        function move-tozip
        {
        param([string]$filedest)
            $Shell = New-Object -com Shell.Application
            $b = $shell.namespace($zippath.ToString())
            $b.CopyHere($filedest.tostring())
            #Remove-Item -Path $filedest
        }
    }
start-job -InitializationScript $func -ScriptBlock {move-tozip $args[0]} -ArgumentList $file
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to wait for a job to complete is to give it a name and tell `Wait-Job` to wait on the task with that name, your script will wait for the job with the name `WaitForMe` to complete and then run the rest of your code once it has.

Using the `-Name` paramter with your code below:

```
$func = 
{
    function Move-ToZip
    { 
      Param([string[]]$path, [string]$zipfile)

      if (-not $zipfile.EndsWith('.zip')) {$zipfile += '.zip'} 

      if (-not (test-path $zipfile))
      { 
        set-content $zipfile ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18)) 
      }

      $shell = (new-object -com shell.application).NameSpace($zipfile) 

      foreach($file in $path)
      {
        $shell.CopyHere($file)
        start-sleep -milliseconds 100
      }
    } 
}


Start-Job -Name "WaitForMe" -InitializationScript $func -ScriptBlock {Move-ToZip -path $args[0] -zipfile $args[1]} -ArgumentList "D:\data.log", "D:\datazip.zip"

Write-Host "Waiting for job to complete"

Wait-Job -Name "WaitForMe"

Write-Host "Job has completed :D"
```

**To zip one file or folder**

```
-ArgumentList "D:\testfile.log", "D:\datazip.zip"
```

**To zip multiple files or folders**

```
-ArgumentList @("D:\testfile.log","D:\testFolder1"), "D:\testzip.zip"
```

**EDIT 17/12/2015**

I've adapted code from [This MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrydixon/archive/2014/08/08/zipping-a-single-file-with-powershell.aspx) to the Move-ToZip function as the previous code didnt work for me at all, i've tested the above code successfully on files and folders. I have not tested the performance of this method, if you wish to compress/zip multiple large files/folders i would highly suggest looking into using a known working library or third party utility like 7zip.

Comment: Did the move-tozip function work on your script ? 'cause it didn't work on mine

Comment: i conducted my tests with this for loop `for($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++) {$i}` in the ScriptBlock which worked.Looking at the `Move-ToZip` function, the `$zippath` variable has not been defined which may be the cause.

Comment: This is just part of my code. What I want to focus here is the copy process which doesn't seem to work within start-job scriptblock

Comment: Please see my latest edit, i could not get the `Move-ToZip` function working so i made some modifications to it, with my edited code i have been able to successfully zip one or more files into a new or existing zip file.

Comment: Dont know why but your code didn't work on my lap :| The `move-tozip` function work fine if I run it out side of the `start-job`'s `scriptblock`

Comment: oh sorry, it just doesn't work with a large file. I tried a 100mb file. but it work well with small one. I guess I have to use other tools rather than pure shell object. anw, thankyou alot :)

Comment: I had a feeling the simple .NET method had some limitations, for consistency and efficiency i would highly suggest using a third party utility like 7zip or a library that is able to handle large files. :)